# Serialize and load FabricJS group

Tags: fabricjs

I'm attempting to group all of the freedraw objects on a canvas, scale and serialize the group, and then load the group onto another canvas.

Currently, I'm grouping all of the objects on canvas with this code.

```
var group = new fabric.Group(canvas.getObjects(), {
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});
```

After this step, I'm not sure how to proceed. If I wasn't dealing with groups, I'd stringify the canvas and then use loadFromJSON. However, I don't think I can just stringify the group. And when I try to use canvas.add() I get a max callback error. Do I need to turn the group into a path object first? 
Here's a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xvxh6d3L/6/

If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it. I'm very stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the maximum callback error, as you need to remove all of the objects that are in the group from the canvas, before you add the group to the canvas.

As far as making them objects, you can use `JSON.stringify(group)`, and then use `fabric.util.enlivenObjects` to convert the `JSON.parse`'d object back into a fabric object. Afterwards, this 'enlived' object can be re-added to a canvas.

You can also use `fabric.Object.toJSON` method, if you don't want all properties saved.